# How to force android to start LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-authenticator

I want to force my app to run the `LoginActivity` if there is no account present.

I've done the following but still when I launch the app in the emulator, I have `MainActivityTest` coming up.

For now I have no Account for my app on the emulator so I expect to simply see the Login screen. However, what I see seems like the `MainActivityTest` is running

```
public class AccountAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "AccountAuthenticator";
    public AccountAuthenticator(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(final AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
                             final String accountType, final String authTokenType,
                             final String[] requiredFeatures, final Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(KEY_INTENT, intent);
        return bundle;

    }
  ...
}

public class AccountAuthenticatorService extends Service {

    private static AccountAuthenticator AUTHENTICATOR;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT) ? getAuthenticator()
                .getIBinder() : null;
    }

    private AccountAuthenticator getAuthenticator() {
        if (AUTHENTICATOR == null)
            AUTHENTICATOR = new AccountAuthenticator(this);
        return AUTHENTICATOR;
    }
}

public class LoginActivity extends RoboSherlockAccountAuthenticatorActivity {
    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction()))
            intent.addCategory(CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }
}
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` is like below

```
   <application
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:label="myapp" >
       <activity
        android:name=".ui.ui.MainActivityTest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.myapp.AccountAuthenticatorService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":auth" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
        <!--
            No intent-filter here! This activity is only ever launched by
            someone who explicitly knows the class name
        -->
    </activity>
   </application
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: So you don't want to set intent-filters for LoginActivity. You want your service to do that job. Right?

Comment: yes. I want LoginActivity to only be shown when the account for my app isn't present on the phone. Also, user should not be able to do anything else if they haven't logged in...

Answer (score 3):

It would be simple if you put value in shared preference once if you complete login process.
and every time when you launch application, once check the sharedpreference value and navigate to activities

```
 Boolean mobile_register_flag = sharedpref.getBoolean("mobile_register_flag", false);

 if (!mobile_register_flag) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FlashView.this,
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FlashView.this,
                    ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: hmm so in my `MainActiviy` I check to see if the value exists in shared pref. If so, start some activity which can only be seen by logged in users, if not start `LoginActivity` and after logging in populate the shared preference? This would work ok but what if I have 10 activities and out of those 9 require the user to be logged in...will I need to check for shared preference before starting each activity?

Comment: I think you are following application flow like app starts with one activity and next second activity. so once if you check in the mainactivity then there may not be any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch the app in the emulator, MainActivityTest coming up because your AndroidManifest has:

```
   <activity
    android:name=".ui.ui.MainActivityTest"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

If you want to launch LoginActivity  by default, use

```
   <activity
    android:name="com.myapp.LoginActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Else, if you want to display LoginActivity as the first activity based on some conditions, then

1. In android manifest, keep MainActivityTest as the default
   activity
2. In MainActivityTest->onCreate, check the condition
   and if condition is true, launch LoginActivity

Comment: I am following the github android app. In their manifest they seem to have HomeActivity as the MAIN: https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/AndroidManifest.xml#L35 . However, in the `onCreate` they aren't checking for a condition to launch `LoginActivity` https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/user/HomeActivity.java#L96 Any idea how they are doing it?

Comment: The activity which you keep as main will be the one that is launched by default when the application icon is clicked. It is your wish which activity you want to display first. Since you mentioned in the question, that you want to launch LoginActivity, so I suggested that it should have the standard MAIN action to make it the main entry point. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).